# Can't execute update-binary in recovery

Tags: android, bash, shell, recovery

This is my first question and hopefully I am making my question clear.
I am trying to make a flashable zip for the first time, it contains a shell script, `TweakV4AndVol.sh` which I hope to run in recovery. The `updater-script` is like this:

```
ui_print("ViPER4Android and VolumeBooster Tweak");
ui_print("Mounting System partition...");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");
package_extract_dir("shell", "/tmp");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/TweakV4AndVol.sh");
ui_print("Applying tweak...");
run_program("/tmp/TweakV4AndVol.sh");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/system"); 
ui_print("Completed!");
```

and `TweakV4AndVol.sh` is like this:

```
#!/sbin/sh
sed -i.bak 's%<ctl name="DEC4 Volume" value="84" />%<ctl name="DEC4 Volume" value="100" />%' /system/etc/mixer_paths.xml
sed -i.bak '/deep_buffer {/ , /}/ d' /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
```

I then manually created the path: `META-INF > com > google > android > update-binary updater-script` and `shell > TweakV4AndVol.sh`. update-binary was fetched from my device's latest CyanogenMOD nightly ROM.
Next I created a zip file with WinRAR, Store compression. I **didn't** sign the flashable because I didn't turn on signature check for TWRP (2.8.7.0).
I then got these error messages:
`E: Error executing updater binary in zip '/data/media/0//CyanDelta/v4voltweak.zip'`
`E: Error installing zip file '/data/media/0//CyanDelta/v4voltweak.zip'`

I've Googled for update-binary and tried multiple methods, including the one from my CM nightlies, Xposed Framework, and even tried SuperSU alternative (use updater-script as a dummy file) but all were giving me the same error, I suppose the problem should lie somewhere in update-binary but searching for hours doesn't benefit. My friends couldn't figure out what happened either as they told me the archive looks fine to them. Any idea is welcomed. Thanks.

---

Update: The flashable is finally working after these modifications:
1. Change

```
sed -i.bak '/deep_buffer {/ , /}/ d' /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
```

into

```
sed -i.bak '/deep_buffer {/,/}/ d' /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
```

and change the first line to

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

(Removing the spaces). This caused a "Unsupported Command" error in bash. As for the second change... I dunno why but that's what I did.
I also modified the default environment on UltraEdit, from DOS to UNIX; and the encoding, from UTF to ANSI. It does flash now though script didn't successfully make the changes, however that'll be much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try extracting one of the zips you are ripping the binaries from, and recompressing it your way to make sure WinRAR isn't to blame? If that worked, it would be easy to merge in your changes piece by piece until it stops working, and narrow the cause down.